# Не работает парсер, ошибки не выдает. Парсер простой

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup

Вот мой код

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
user=UserAgent()
profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override',user.random)
driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get('https://rabota.ykt.ru/') 

#Это смена юзер агента
time.sleep(10)

def rabota(table):
    soup=BeatifulSoup(table,'lxml')
    vacansii=soup.findAll(class_='class="r-vacancy_list_item ng-scope')
    for vacansia in vacansii:
        knopka=vacansia.find(class_='r-vacancy_title').text
        print(knopka)

def main():
    table=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.r-vacancy_list').get_attribute('innerHTML')



if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Что я не так сделал?

Comment: опишите возникшую у вас ошибку или проблему, чтобы люди знали что нужно решать.

Comment: Мне кажется, или Вы нигде не запускаете функцию `rabota`? Может, её запуск нужно дописать в `main`?